# Error compiling LibSVM with MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab, libsvm

Since investing in a new machine, I've been moving all my research over but I have been facing trouble when compiling LibSVM within MATLAB using the `make` command which outputs the following warning:

> svmpredict.c:17:36: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
>   [-Wreturn-type] int print_null(const char *s,...) {}

I have no experience of coding with C and am a bit baffled by the warning. Can I ignore the warning? Or will it affect how LibSVM performs?

Comment: It's only a warning (compiler trying to help you spot bugs), so it means the compile completed (unless there were other errors).  Try the svmpredict/svmtrain functions; if they don't generate errors, the chances are it compiled fine.

Comment: Sorry to have to say this, but libsvm is one of the ugliest written libraries I have ever seen. It's really sad that it became so widespread... If it works, then it should be OK, in spite of that warning.